# Why can't I call ToList on a WhereSelectEnumerableIterator(Of T, String)

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to use linq to extract values from a set of items. There is a possibility that the field doesn't exist, or that it is empty, so I want to filter by the fields that are not null and are not empty. The field values are of a numeric type and I want to project them to a string. The return on this query is a `WhereSelectEnumerableIterator(Of NestedTableItem, String)`. **EDIT: Looks like this is the appropriate return type.** <strike>I'm struggling to understand why this is still projecting the `NestedTableItem` along side the String.</strike> In the end I want to call ToList on the query, but I get an exception that ToList is not found on that type.

.NET Version: `4.5.1`

References:
`Microsoft.VisualBasic`, `System`, `System.Core`, `System.IO`, `System.Linq`, `System.Runtime`, `System.Xml`, `System.Xml.Linq`

Imports:
`Imports System`,
`Imports System.Text`,
`Imports System.Collections.Generic`,
`Imports System.Linq`,
`Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices`,
`Imports System.Xml`,
`Imports System.IO`

```
Dim aasItems As IEnumerable(Of NestedTableItem) = aasTable.NestedTableItems
Dim query = From item In aasItems
            Let field = item.AllFields.ValueFields.Find("AASProposedTotalMinCreditHours")
            Where field IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not field.IsEmpty
            Select New String(field.Numeric9Value.ToString())
Dim aasMinStringList = query.ToList()
```

Specific exception message:

`Public member 'ToList' on type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator(Of NestedTableItem,String)' not found.`

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Updated title to better match question.**

Comment: Where did you write `ToList()` on that query? Did you try enclosing the LINQ query inside set of parentheses and then call `ToList()`?

Comment: Siva, I added that line.

Comment: Do you have the same result if you do `Select field.Numeric9Value.ToString()` ?

Comment: @Lempface Then you are probably missing an Import statement for System.Linq as ToList is an extension method

Comment: I have `System.Linq` in my imports. The reason I used a `New String` was because vb.net throws an error if you just call `ToString()` because `ToString()` already exists on `Object`. I tried wrapping the `field.Numeric9Value.ToString` in parens as well, same result.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I considered this as well. Perhaps that is the correct return type and the issue is related to the `ToList()` call. I feel like I've done this kind of projection hundreds of times before without issue. This is being executed by an ECM product.

Comment: @Lempface Is it possible you're not including the assembly `System.Core.dll` where `ToList()` is defined?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply Ed, I have `Microsoft.VisualBasic`, `System`, `System.Core`, `System.IO`, `System.Linq`, `System.Runtime`, `System.Xml`, `System.Xml.Linq` added as references.

Comment: Hmm. Another long shot: In the project properties, what's the .NET version?

Comment: The .NET version is 4.5.1

Comment: To me, the error means that something in the query is not being translated the way it looks.  I'd start with the inferred type of `field`: what's the return type of `ValueFields.Find`?  Do you have `Option Strict On` or is VB allowed to try to muddle through?

Comment: `ValueFields.Find` returns a `ValueField` object or null if the search string is not found in the internal collection. `Option Strict Off` is the current configuration.

Comment: What are the types of the relevant objects, such as `NestedTableItems`, `ValueFields`, `AllFields` ?

Comment: `NestedTableItems` is a `NestedTableItemList` object, `AllFields` is a `FieldList` object and `ValueFields` is a `ValueFieldList` object. These are classes from the ECM API that I'm integrating with. All of these _lists_ implement: `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Where does this `NestableItem` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by casting the query to IEnumerable(Of String).

```
Dim aasItems As IEnumerable(Of NestedTableItem) = aasTable.NestedTableItems
Dim query As IEnumerable(Of String) = _ 
            From item In aasItems
            Let field = item.AllFields.ValueFields.Find("AASProposedTotalMinCreditHours")
            Where field IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not field.IsEmpty
            Select New String(field.Numeric9Value.ToString())
Dim aasMinStringList = query.ToList()
```

I'm still unsure why the original code did not work. If anyone has any insight, I'd appreciate understanding more.

Comment: I kept this aside for a while (a long while at this point) planning to come back to it when I had a chance.  I don't see any obvious reason why the original code wouldn't work.  I built up a minimal example that would support the original posted query, and the type was inferred as `IEnumerable(Of String)` without needing to cast.  I tested in the latest (or very near latest) version of VS 2017.  There might have been a quirk relating to something specific about one of the API collection classes...

Comment: ... As I used a `List(Of NestedTableItem)` rather than writing a separate class for that, and my equivalent of `ValueFieldList` inherited .NET's `List(Of T)`.